# Email Message on Case Feed - Is it Possible To Show the "From" Address Not the "To"

Tags: feeditem, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking, casefeed

We are using Service Console with Feed Enabled Layouts on Cases. We are using a programmatic solution to consume Email replies to existing Cases and save the Email on the Case. In the Case Feed an EmailMessageEvent gets posted. The Feed shows the "To" field by default. I would like it to show the "From" field. Is this possible?

[image]